# WAVEFORMATEX parameters for DSD64

Tags: windows, audio, wasapi, audioformat

The Windows WASAPI does not provide a function to list all supported audio formats of an audio device. Instead, one has to provide a `WAVEFORMATEX` structure with the desired format parameters and use [IsFormatSupported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nf-audioclient-iaudioclient-isformatsupported) to check whether that particular format is supported. There is support for IEC61937 DST/DSD, but I can not figure out how to set the format parameters for e.g. DSD64, and it never provides a closest matching format either. What's wrong with these parameters?

```
WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE_IEC61937 format;
memset(&format, 0, sizeof(WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE_IEC61937));
format.FormatExt.Format.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE;
format.FormatExt.Format.nChannels = 2;
format.FormatExt.Format.nSamplesPerSec = 44100 * 64;
format.FormatExt.Format.wBitsPerSample = 1;
format.FormatExt.Format.nBlockAlign = format.FormatExt.Format.nChannels * 64;
format.FormatExt.Format.nAvgBytesPerSec = format.FormatExt.Format.nChannels * format.FormatExt.Format.nSamplesPerSec / 8;
format.FormatExt.Format.cbSize = sizeof(WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE_IEC61937) - sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX);
format.FormatExt.Samples.wValidBitsPerSample = 1;
format.FormatExt.dwChannelMask = SPEAKER_FRONT_LEFT | SPEAKER_FRONT_RIGHT;
format.FormatExt.SubFormat = KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_IEC61937_DST;
format.dwEncodedSamplesPerSec = 0;
format.dwEncodedChannelCount = 2;
format.dwAverageBytesPerSec = 0;
```

Comment: Why is nSamplesPerSec multiplied by 64?

Comment: Because that's the sample rate of DSD64 (2.822 MHz).

Answer (score 0):

I think `dwEncodedSamplesPerSec` should be `44100`.

The [IEC-61937 format doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/representing-formats-for-iec-61937-transmissions)
says:

> The `dwEncodedSamplesPerSec`, `dwEncodedChannelCount`, and `dwAverageBytesPerSec` members of `WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE_IEC61937` describe the sampling rate, number of channels, and bit rate in bytes of the stream of the audio stream after it has been decoded.

`ksmedia.h`, the header file, says the same thing, but adds that the byte rate "can be zero".

Comment: DSD (KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_IEC61937_DST) is a non-PCM format. That page only lists a few examples of PCM(-based) formats and states that `*_DST` is not supported by Microsoft's driver (and thus documentation). I tried it, but it still won't find the format or a close match.